# Need to understand the behaviour of BinarySearch and IndexOf methods

Tags: c#, list

I have List and its values is ("Brandenburg","Alabama" and "Alberta"). When i used `BinarySearch("Brandenburg")` method, it returns -4 instead of 0. but i can get the correct index, when sorted this list. Why it returns wrong value if I use the unsorted list?. And I have also get the correct index from `IndexOf("Brandenburg")` method. Which method is useful that i can use?.

Thanks in Advance,
Prithivi

Comment: normally binarysearch work on  sorted list/array. But you can also modify if your list follow a specific pattern. But in case of completely random order. binarySearch will not work

Comment: So you've carefully read documentation for both methods... please clarify what exactly was not clear there.

Comment: if you look to definition of binary search you'll see that binary search is a search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a sorted array. so it works only on sorted arrays.
for IndexOf, have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It MUST be sorted, to use binary search. The reason you're getting `-4` is;

Your collection isn't sorted and for binary search the list will 'cut' in half each iteration. So:

When it starts, the topIndex == 0 and bottom = 2

```
TopIndex ->    (0) "Brandenburg",
               (1) "Alabama" 
BottomIndex -> (2) "Alberta
```

The binarysearch will check the item in the middle: (2-0) / 2 = 1. If you're searching for `Brandenburg`. It will compare `Alabama` with your search item. The letter `B` is 'bigger' than letter 'A'. So it moves the topIndex to index 1.

```
               (0) "Brandenburg",
TopIndex ->    (1) "Alabama" 
BottomIndex -> (2) "Alberta
```

Then it will compare to the next 'middle' item. In this case again `Alabama`. `(2-1) / 2 = 1`. It will also be compare to the bottomIndex, but this is the last one.

**When binarysearch returns a negative number, it means that the item cannot be found. The negative number is the Index where it should be inserten.** `(-result -1)` So if you want the new item added, it should be inserted on index `(--4 -1) == 3`

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain how binary search works.

Say you have this array:

```
{1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20}
```

And I want to find the index of 15. What binary search will do is that it looks at the middle of the array, 7. Is 7 greater or less than 15? If it is less than 15, do the same thing again on the second half of the array (10, 15, 20). If it is greater than 15, do it on the first half (1, 3, 5). If it is equal to 15, then that means 15 is found.

This means that the array must be sorted for binary search to work. This explains why doing a binary search on your array returns a negative number. Because obviously, the method can't find the string you requested using the binary search algorithm.

You can get the correct index with `IndexOf`. This is because `IndexOf` uses a linear search to find the item. It looks at each element in the array and compare to the one that you're finding. Therefore, whether the array is sorted doesn't matter.

Note: I have not read the source code of `IndexOf`. It might use a binary search if it finds that the array is sorted. This is only my guess.